# IBM Cognos Configuration of Content Store with db2

Tags: db2, windows-server-2012-r2, cognos, cognos-bi

Can someone please elaborate the Point "c" while configuring IBM Cognos.
which user id and password is required. Do i have to create UserId's in DB2 or in Windows?

Procedure

> In IBM Cognos Configuration, configure a content store database.
>
> Note
>
> The information that you enter is used to generate a script that you
>   use to create the content store database on the data node computer.
>
> a) In the Explorer pane, under Data Access > Content Manager, click
>   Content Store.
>   b) In the Database server and port number field,
>   enter the name of the computer and the port number on which you
>   installed IBM DB2® Enterprise Server. For example, enter
>   servername:50000, where servername is the name of the data node
>   computer and 50000 is the default port number that is used by IBM DB2.
>       On Linux operating systems, the default port number is 50001.
>   c) Click the Value field next to the User ID and password property,
>   click the edit icon, and enter the User ID and Password for your IBM
>   DB2 user, and click OK.
>       In the Properties pane, for the Database name property, enter a name for your content store database.
>
> The default name is cm.

Comment: The userid/password most likely needs to be on the Db2-server machine. So if the Db2-server runs on Windows-Server, then the userid needs to exist there as a windows user (or exist in the Domain to which the server belongs, if any).  Apart from the userid/password needing to be correct on the Db2-server machine, the user (or its group) needs to be permitted to connect to the database. You cannot create users inside Db2, the users are in the operating-system or domain of the Db2-server.

Answer (score 0):

The user which is defined in the content store user and password properties is an entity defined in the host data base.  That user needs to have certain capabilities defined for the host data base in order to perform manipulations of the content store data base, including being able to add and alter tables.

This document tells you the necessary settings for some of the major data base vendors, including Db2.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21341241

Answer (score 0):

By user-id it means the use that has full control over a database(the Cognos Content Store is the database that Cognos Content Manager service uses) in Db2; A Db2 user is actually a Windows user(in Db2 to add a new user, first you have to create a new user in your OS and then tell DB2 that he/she has a set of permissions on a particular db).

The default Db2 user that has full control over all databases by default is the Db2 instance-user that is created when you create a Db2 instance in the installation process and this user is also is a Windows user(you can login into Windows with his/her username and password).

You just need these items to set up content store db:

1. A Db2 instance with a valid ip(or hostname) and the Db2 port(default is 50000)
2. A database hosted in the instance
3. Username(it's the user-id we are talking about) and password of the user that has full controll over the database inside the Db2 instance

Btw, I'm assuming you are on Windows but the procedure is the same for Db2 LUW on other OSes, Also setting up a Db2 instance/db or adding new users is ought to be done before all this.

Hope it helped.